# Simultaneously displaying two countdown timers on two different activities

Tags: java, android, timer

I currently have a countdown timer on my second activity. What I am trying to do is set the textView on my main activity to the value of the countdown timer on my secondActivity. Here is my code for the countdown timer.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // put your logic here to set the time with hourPicked and minPicked variables
                timer = new CounterClass((hours * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 1000), 1000);
                String hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d:"), hours, minutes);
                textViewTime.setText(hms);
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                hours = newVal;
                timer = new CounterClass((hours * 60 * 1000), 1000);
                String hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes);
                textViewTime.setText(hms);
            }
        });

        noPickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                minutes = newVal;
                timer = new CounterClass((minutes * 1000), 1000);
                String hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes);
                textViewTime.setText(hms);
                Bundle timerBundle = new Bundle();
                timerBundle.putInt("%02d:%02d", Integer.parseInt(hms));
                Intent timerIntent = new Intent();


            }
        })
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);


    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }


}}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Run your timer in `Service` or `IntentService`

2- Post events(messages) from service on each tick. 
 You can accomplish that 
using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). It would be good to also send event to `Service` requesting immediate update.

Personally i would use Otto as its so much more convenient to use.

Edit:
What i mean is. Make your timer separated from `Activity` by placing it inside `Service`

Then in your `onTick()` method

start  new `Otto` event and pass current counter time with it example:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          bus.post(new TimerTickEvent(millisUntilFinished));
}
```

You can listen for this `Event` in your `Activity`

```
@Subscribe public void eventTimerTick(TimerTickEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!

      event.getTimeToEnd();
}
```

I higly advice you to read about Otto Before using it as it requires registering on activity resum and unregistering on activity pause

Comment: Im not really sure how to use those in this situation could you please post some code to show how they could be used

Comment: Because thats external library, i gave you link to it

Comment: Sry Im such a noob to programming is there any way to do it without downloading anything

Comment: Yes, i talked also about LocalBrodcastManager its build in to android and work very similar to Otto. But it requires a lot of setup.

Comment: Would there be any way of doing this using intents

Comment: LocalBrodcastManager sends intents

Comment: Oh alright could you post some example code using LocalBrodcastManager

Comment: Let me google that for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager